# Erlang YAWS https tax

Tags: ssl, erlang, yaws

Since everything should be https, I enabled it, and noticed how much slower https is compared to http.

I have a Ubuntu/YAWS server in Dallas. I start YAWS using "yaws --daemon --nodebug"

If I do

> time curl -i  https://share.spreadsheetconverter.com/echo/

and

> time curl -i  http://share.spreadsheetconverter.com/echo/

from the server itself, https takes about 100ms and http 20ms, i.e. the difference is 80ms.

When we try from Sweden, Europe, https is 1400ms and http is 350ms. These figures can be logical, due to the latency over the Atlantic.

---

However, now to the strange thing.

I also have a Windows/IIS server in Dallas.

If I compare simple http-get request on both servers, the difference https-penalty is much bigger for the YAWS server than for IIS. (I have also tested Tomcat, and it behaves similar to IIS).

It also seems to be latency dependent, i.e. the longer from the server you are, the bigger is the difference between IIS and YAWS.

When I do similar tests with the IIS server in Dallas, from Sweden, https is 1000ms, and http is the same as for YAWS, i.e. IIS is much faster (400ms) at https than Yaws. It is almost as if YAWS makes an extra network call.

I have also been experimenting with

> http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

and just extracted the SSL time reported by them. Notice that SSL time increases faster for YAWS

```
          |  YAWS  |  IIS
Dallas    |  79ms  |  75ms 
New York  |  212ms |  87ms
Amsterdam |  503ms | 315ms
```

---

Ok, what should I do?

- Is there a bug in my YAWS setup?
- Will placing NGINX in front of YAWS solve the problem, and let Nginx handle https?
- Is there a bug in my SSL cert? Can they be faster or slower? I have checked with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

---

Update 2015-08-20

I updated to yaws 2.0, and yes, the performance difference is still there.

By using

```
curl -v --trace-time --trace-ascii echo.log https://share.spreadsheetconverter.com/echo/
```

and comparing it with

```
curl -v --trace-time --trace-ascii server1.log https://www.spreadsheetserver.com/server1/
```

I compared all the rows, I see that we loose 300ms at one single row.

This is how it looks when we talk to Yaws 2.0

```
17:37:54.606668 == Info: TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
17:37:54.606692 => Send SSL data, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: ......Jb.9...#.^
17:37:54.758726 == Info: TLSv1.2, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
17:37:54.758761 <= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
17:37:55.107695 == Info: TLSv1.2, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
17:37:55.107726 <= Recv SSL data, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: ..........Y.xV.!
17:37:55.107784 == Info: SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA
```

and this when I talk to IIS

```
17:40:25.247308 == Info: TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
17:40:25.247329 => Send SSL data, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: ........f4..qh:(
17:40:25.376893 == Info: TLSv1.0, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
17:40:25.376925 <= Recv SSL data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: .
17:40:25.377081 == Info: TLSv1.0, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
17:40:25.377103 <= Recv SSL data, 16 bytes (0x10)
0000: ....C..'.A,..'R.
17:40:25.377142 == Info: SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / AES128-SHA
```

For both Yaws and IIS, the first "Send SSL data" takes 150 ms

For IIS, two immediate "Recv SSL data" follows with no delay.

However, in the Yaws case, we have to wait 350ms for the first "Recv SSL data", and then the next is immediate

It is like something is async in IIS, but sync in Yaws. In IIS, the data to be received is combined with the ack of the Send, but in Yaws, it is two separate requests.

All these requests have to pass the Atlantic Ocean. If I instead do it with the same data center, the differences are much much smaller.

Comment: As you point out it looks like there's more traffic during handshake with Yaws. Is `Identity Authentication` configured the same for different webservers? In Yaws it's the `verify` option in the ssl section. Enabling authentication of both ends would cause more packets during handshake.

Comment: I added   "verify = 1" to the ssl-section in yaws.confg, no difference.

Comment: With questions like this it's always helpful to include the version of Yaws you're using, and also the version of the underlying Erlang system.

Comment: Yaws 1.98, Erl 17.4,  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Could it be a routing problem? It's suspicious that the local ping times are so similar. If SSL were the problem, you should see a fairly constant addition rather than a multiplier.

Comment: I do not think it is a routing problem, since the http times are identical, both locally, and when the distance increases.

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of Yaws, 1.99?

Comment: No, I have not tried 1.99, since I had some rebar issues with embedded YAWS, which I wanted to do at the same time. If you say that there might be a difference for this, I will check.

Comment: I upgraded to Yaws 1.99 + a little more, but the result is still the same. Noticable difference between IIS and Yaws for https.

Comment: Upgraded to Yaws 2.0.2, no difference

Comment: Have you tried having both use the same TLS version and cipher suite? IIS is TLSv1.0 with AES128-SHA, YAWS is TLSv1.2 with ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA which may be a bit more expensive depending on how things are set up and built. The TLS stack may just be slower in Erlang (which seems unlikely considering how much stuff runs it these days, but *could* be a possibility).

Comment: No, no tried that. However, Since the difference are SO HUGE, we are talking about one extra round trip. This could be verified with wireshare or similar. I started adding nginx as a rev proxy and handle the certs there instead.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx or HAproxy can solve this problem.
You should terminate your HTTPS traffic on proxy node. And after that you should pass HTTP traffic on erlang node.
Moreover keep the erlang node in internet without proxy is not a good practice.

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is an option. However, I always want as little software as possible, and since I do not have a lot of static pages, there is no performance advantage by offloading that to nginx. Please explain "Moreover keep the erlang node in internet without proxy is not a good practice"

Comment: There are some kind of attacks on HTTP layer. For example http slowloris. Nginx not affected by slowloris and many other. I think better to be safe with fast proxy in front of the erlang code